# How to know if a CancellationToken has a registered cancellation method?

Tags: c#, .net, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I have a parent object that contains a `CancellationTokenSource`. This object passes its `CancellationToken` into a process that communicates sequentially with external services. Whenever a call is made to an external service, the `CancellationToken` is registered to a method that will allow the process to stop waiting for the external service to respond:

```
myObj.CancellationTokenRegistration.Dispose();
myObj.CancellationTokenRegistration = myObj.CancellationToken.Register(() => CancelMethod(myObj));
```

Given only the `CancellationTokenSource`, is there a way to know that a cancellation method has been registered against the token?

Comment: Why do you want to know? The fact that you're even asking this suggests you're not using cancellation tokens the way you're meant to. I can't rule out the possibility that you have a legitimate need for it, but if you do, I'm interested in knowing what that might be.

Comment: When my service is restarted, I need to reconstruct the callbacks and CancellationTokenRegistrations that were present before shutting down. There are situations where, after a restart, I need to cancel but nothing happens (because I did not recreate the registration correctly). I would like to proactively detect if a token is unregistered and clean it up (or located and fix the bug in the code).

Comment: Huh. It seems like you're making things very difficult for yourself, but it certainly is a special case. Since you have control of the callback, and it seems like you only need to check whether the registration succeeded when the callback is actually called, would it be possible to modify that callback to simply increment a global counter? Your other code can then verify that the counter got incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Without using reflection (or other types of voodoo) to look at the internal state of the `CancellationTokenSource` there's no way to know if some code has added any registrations.

If you do want to use reflection you should look at this field:

```
private volatile SparselyPopulatedArray<CancellationCallbackInfo>[] m_registeredCallbacksLists;
```

Answer (score 0):

The m_callbackInfo field seems to contain the same information.

```
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Action test = CancelMethod;
        CancellationTokenRegistration = cts.Token.Register(test);
        var fieldInfo = typeof(CancellationTokenRegistration).GetField("m_callbackInfo", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        object fieldValue = fieldInfo.GetValue(CancellationTokenRegistration);
        var callbackFieldInfo = fieldValue.GetType().GetField("Callback", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var callbackValue = callbackFieldInfo.GetValue(fieldValue);
        var stateForCallbackFieldInfo = fieldValue.GetType().GetField("StateForCallback", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var stateForCallbackValue = stateForCallbackFieldInfo.GetValue(fieldValue);
        // stateForCallbackValue == CancelMethod; if Token.Register is called with one of the Action<object> arguments 
        // callbackValue == CancelMethod

        private void CancelMethod()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some rough code using reflection to enumerate registered Actions (works as expected with .Net 4.7.1):

```
public static IEnumerable<Action<object>> Registrations(this CancellationToken token)
{
        var sourceFieldInfo = typeof(CancellationToken).GetField("m_source", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        var cancellationTokenSource = (CancellationTokenSource)sourceFieldInfo.GetValue(token);

        var callbacksFieldInfo = typeof(CancellationTokenSource).GetField("m_registeredCallbacksLists", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        var callbaskLists = (Array)callbacksFieldInfo.GetValue(cancellationTokenSource);

        foreach (var sparselyPopulatedArray in callbaskLists)
        {
            if (sparselyPopulatedArray == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var sparselyPopulatedArrayType = sparselyPopulatedArray.GetType();

            var tailFieldInfo = sparselyPopulatedArrayType.GetProperty("Tail", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            var tail = tailFieldInfo.GetValue(sparselyPopulatedArray);

            var sparselyPopulatedArrayFragmentType = tail.GetType();

            var elementsTypeFieldInfo = sparselyPopulatedArrayFragmentType.GetField("m_elements", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            var elements = (Array)elementsTypeFieldInfo.GetValue(tail);

            foreach (var callbackInfo in elements)
            {
                if (callbackInfo == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var callbackInfoType = callbackInfo.GetType();

                var callbackFieldInfo = callbackInfoType.GetField("Callback", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

                var callback = (Action<object>)callbackFieldInfo.GetValue(callbackInfo);

                if (callback != null)
                {
                    yield return callback;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```